# Modification via Javascript DOM of member page login in weebly

Tags: javascript, dom, weebly

I want to modify the member page login in weebly `(apps/member/login)` ,

I want to put this code in weebly in order to modify the login English page.

My code is :

```
var title4 = document.querySelector(".login-title"); 
var title1 = document.querySelector(".reset-password"); 
var title2 = document.querySelector(".membership-right-action"); 
var title3 = document.querySelector(".login-email"); 
var title5 = document.querySelector(".login-password"); 
title4.textContent = "connexion"; 
title1.textContent = "mot de passe"; 
title2.textContent = "se connecter"; 
title3.setAttribute("placeholder", "email"); 
title5.setAttribute("placeholder", "password");
```

Where can I put this code in weebly in order to have a French page login?

Thanks

Comment: Please can you improve the formatting of your question?

Answer (score 0):

These /apps/member/* pages cannot currently be modified.